# qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped Segmentation fault - EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16f603ff0)

Tags: c++

I need to randomly populate this 2d array with 5 different items. The amount of each item is passed as a percentage, along with the dimension of the 2d array, at runtime.

This is what I tried but I got a segmentation fault error in the terminal. When I tried to run the debugger I got this error:

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16f603fe8)
```

.h file

```
#ifndef LEVEL_H
#define LEVEL_H

#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Mario.h"


using namespace std;

//Class for level
class Level{
public:
    //Constructor for level, which takes in the array dimensions
    //Also takes in the percentages chosen by the file, for how many coins, nothing spaces, goomba and koopa's
    //are present in the array (world)
    Level(int dimension, int coinPrct, int nothingPrct, int goombaPcrt, int koopaPrct, int mushPcrt);
    
    //Default destructor
    ~Level();

    void populate();

    char nextItem();
    
//Private member variables
private:
    char *m_levelAry;
    int m_coins;
    int m_nothing;
    int m_goombas;
    int m_koopas;
    int m_mushrooms;
    int m_dimension;
};

#endif
```

.cpp file

```css
#include "Level.h"

//Constructor handles dimensions of the array and odds of how frequent coins, enemies and nothing spawn
Level::Level(int dimension, int coinPrct, int nothingPrct, int goombaPcrt, int koopaPrct, int mushPcrt){
    m_dimension = dimension;
    m_levelAry = new char [dimension * dimension];
    m_coins = round((coinPrct/100.0) * (dimension * dimension));
    m_nothing = round((nothingPrct/100.0) * (dimension * dimension));
    m_goombas = round((goombaPcrt/100.0) * (dimension * dimension));
    m_koopas = round((koopaPrct/100.0) * (dimension * dimension));
    m_mushrooms = round((mushPcrt/100.0) * (dimension * dimension));

    /*
    srand(time(NULL));
    
    for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < dimension; j++){
            m_levelAry[i * dimension + j] = nextItem();
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < dimension; i++){
            cout << m_levelAry[i * dimension + j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    */
}

Level::~Level(){
    delete[] m_levelAry;
}

void Level::populate(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    
    for (int i = 0; i < m_dimension; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < m_dimension; j++){
            m_levelAry[i * m_dimension + j] = nextItem();
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < m_dimension; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < m_dimension; i++){
            cout << m_levelAry[i * m_dimension + j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}


char Level::nextItem(){
    int randItemNum = (rand() % 4) + 1;
    switch (randItemNum){
        case 1:
            if (m_coins != 0){
                m_coins -= 1;
                return 'c';
            } else {
                return nextItem();
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            if (m_nothing != 0){
                m_nothing -= 1;
                return 'x';
            } else {
                return nextItem();
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            if (m_goombas != 0){
                m_goombas -= 1;
                return 'g';
            } else {
                return nextItem();
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            if (m_koopas != 0){
                m_koopas -= 1;
                return 'k';
            } else {
                return nextItem();
            }
            break;
        case 5:
            if (m_mushrooms != 0){
                m_mushrooms -= 1;
                return 'm';
            } else {
                return nextItem();
            }
            break;
        default:
            return NULL;
            break;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Level level1(5, 25, 47, 8, 8, 12);
    level1.populate();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please read the [tour] to the end, and inform yourself at our [help] what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Is this better now?

Comment: No it isn't, how so? Because I edited out just plain nonsense non runnable code snippets for you?

Comment: The debugger should have pointed you to the line of code that caused the error. Did you try stepping through the code with the debugger one line at a time looking at your variables at each step, and verifying calculations are producing the results you are expecting at each step?

Comment: Recommendations: [read up on the Rule of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) and with `m_coins = round((coinPrct/100.0) * (dimension * dimension));` consider instead `m_coins = coinPrct * dimension * dimension / 100;` Probably no need for floating point here. Just divide last.

Comment: Definitely go stepping through with a debugger. Betting on Stack Overflow due to poorly or uncontrolled recursion.

Comment: Yep. It doesn't looks like you have a solid plan for what to do once all of the items have been placed. If every `if (m_whatever != 0)` takes the else, kablooey. Even if most take the else the program can spin off the end of the stack through dumb bad luck.

Comment: @user4581301 your right I'm pretty new to c++. The answer below actually did fix the problem but it is kinda "unsafe" as you said. What would be a better way to go about it?

Comment: `while (true)` loop around the everything that's currently in `nextItem`'s body and get rid of all of the `else` cases. The function will loop around and around until the program hits one of the `return` statements. It may still wind up in a nigh-infinite loop if `rand` consistently spits out the number of a used up case, but it won't overflow and crash anymore.

Comment: A better option is to make an array that contains all of the values in the exact proportions you want, say 42 coins in a row, then 170 goombas, etc and then [shuffle that array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle).

Comment: @user4581301 What would be the best way to shuffle the array?

Comment: @Coder99 See the the bottom three lines of the code example in the second answer (as sorted by current answer scoring) The `populate` function simplifies down to almost nothing and `nextItem` vanishes completely.

Answer (score 2):

The switch case in `Level::nextItem()` never go into case 5.

The range of `int randItemNum = (rand() % 4) + 1;` is 1~4.

When the m_coins, m_nothing, m_goobas, m_koopas all consumed, `Level::nextItem()` will be infinite loop, which will cause segmentation fault in the end.

Note: [gdb](https://www.sourceware.org/gdb/) is helpful for dealing with this kind of problem.

Comment: Side note: This is not a particularly good or safe place to use recursion. Did help find a bug, though.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler, safer population:

```cpp
void Level::populate(){
// starting at the beginning of the array, load it up with the computed 
// numbers of different tiles
    char *locp = m_levelAry;
    memset(locp, m_coins, 'c');
    locp += m_coins;
    memset(locp, m_goombas, 'g');
    locp += m_goombas;
    memset(locp, m_koopas, 'k');
    locp += m_koopas;
    memset(locp, m_mushrooms, 'm');
    locp += m_mushrooms;
    memset(locp, m_nothing, 'x');
    locp += m_nothing; // locp now points to the end of the array, 
                       // assuming enough tiles were generated. Buffer 
                       // overflow if rounding went askew and too many items 
                       // generated.
// set up random number generation 
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 engine(rd());
// shuffle all of the tiles.
    std::shuffle(m_levelAry, locp, engine);
}
```

The code fills up the array with the required number of each tile and then shuffles the array to get a good distribution of tiles.

Side note: I'd compute the number of coins, koopas, goombas, and mushrooms. Nothing would be the remaining space in the array. This prevents problems where the math doesn't round out to exactly fill the array.